# GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found <EOF>

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, graphql-tag

I got the above error on a graphql query, I am using apollo-react by the way and using the Query component for rendering the data

this is my code

```
const GET_VEHICLE_CHECKS = gql`
query getVehicleChecks($uuid: String!) {
  tripDetails(uuid: $uuid){
    departmentAssigned{
      vehicleChecks{
        conditions{
          id
          name
          standard
          valueType
          spinnerItems
        }
      }
    }
  }

`;
```

and this is what my actual query looks like

```
{
  tripDetails(uuid: "c0e7233093b14afa96f39e2b70c047d8"){
    departmentAssigned{
      vehicleChecks{
        conditions{
          id
          name
          standard
          valueType
          spinnerItems
        }
      }
    }
    vehicleConditions{
      id
      condition{
        id
        standard
      }
      value
    }
  }
}
```

I tried changing variable names, but that didn't work

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket `}` at the end of your query.

```
const GET_VEHICLE_CHECKS = gql`
query getVehicleChecks($uuid: String!) {
  tripDetails(uuid: $uuid){
    departmentAssigned{
      vehicleChecks{
        conditions{
          id
          name
          standard
          valueType
          spinnerItems
        }
      }
    }
  }
} <- THIS
`;
```

Comment: This was the answer for me. Too bad the person writing this error message didnt have the sense to make a descriptive message. EOF is vague and someone really shouldnt need to do look up what it means to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is usually cause by a missing `{` or a missing `(` so look for that in your query also look for stray/missing `:`

It could be that your query is empty which will give you the EOF error as well

Comment: @EricAya My answer is more general and applicable then the accepted. Plus it adds more information